# How do I revert to the latest release version of my app for bug fixing?

Tags: android, android-studio, version-control

After pushing an update in the playstore, I make lots of changes to the source code. But the problem is whenever a bug is reported through crashlytics, etc., the source code referenced is the unaltered release version which makes the line numbers in the crash report irrelevant.

So how do I check the latest release version?

Comment: With line number it shows some text, it may be variable name, method name or anything else. with that you can search in the file.

Comment: Can the down voters give reason for down voting this question ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you want to see **exact** error in **exact** line you can do following things.

1. Push to git/svn your app`s release version
2. Pull exact release version back to see error in exact line if you
   changed that file in your current version

Answer (score 0):

One of the way to solve it:

I recommend to know Git before reading the steps.

- Use Git to track your source code (I hope you know Git, if you don't then I recommend to check it out)
- Write your code.
- Once code is done. Git Commit and Push your code.
- Git tag your current code to refer later
- Build APK and ship it.

**Note**: Keep the Git tag name and APK version same for your understanding.

Now when you face crashes in a particular version of your app. Let's say v1.1 then you can just find the Git tag named "v1.1" and see the code of that version and do what you want!